# Getting an error when trying to knit my document using Rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have this code:

````
```{r,echo=TRUE}
lg <- function(x, a = 1, b = 1){
  exp(a+b*x) / (1+exp(a+b*x))
}
```

```{r,echo=TRUE}
for (b in c(1:5)){
  curve(expr = lg(x, 1, b), from = -5, to = 5, n = 100, add= TRUE, col = b)
}
```
````

But when I go to knit the document it gets stuck on line 89 which is the one that starts with `for...` I get an error that says,

> ```
> error in plot.xy(xy.coords(x y) type = type ...)  plot.new has not been called yet 
>
> Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> curve -> lines -> lines.default -> plot.xy
> ```

I need to run these as separate chunks so that the graphs are separate but I'm not sure how to fix this error so I can knit the document.

Comment: Previous to `curve()` there is at least sth. like `plot.new()`missing. Difficult to give further hints: (i) What is your goal, how should the plot look like? (ii) which kind of export? e.g.  html or pdf?

Comment: That's what I was thinking but when I add that then it changes the whole graph.

Comment: I am wanting to export as an html. The graph should look the way it does when you originally run the code.
It only has an error when I try to knit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modifying this might help you:

```
lg <- function(x, a = 1, b = 1){
  exp(a+b*x) / (1+exp(a+b*x))
}
```

```
plot(NA, xlim = c(-5, 5), ylim = c(0, 1))
for (b in c(1:5)){
  curve(expr = lg(x, 1, b), from = -5, to = 5, n = 100, add= TRUE, col = b)
}
```